# Is there any API (i.e node SDK) to know about the existence and service endpoints of peers?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Is there any API (i.e node SDK) to know about the existence and service endpoints of peers? We would like to discover such information dynamically so that we don't have to preconfigure peer information in the client’s configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Great question. There is no API yet, as the peer doesn't expose this information.

However, there is a "service discovery" service that is under planning/development and SDKs will be able to query endpoints of peers, and much more - like what are the root CA certificates of other organizations, etc.

Stay tuned!